# Perl - capture system() error

Tags: perl

I am converting some jpg images to png w/ imagemagick & have the following in perl:

```
system("convert $jpg $png");
print "$?\n";
```

Is there a way to capture the actual errors from imagemagick (rather than just whether or not it executed successfully as I have in the code above)?

note: I use imagemagick solely as an example....this is more a general question on how to capture errors from whatever program that system() executes.

thx!

Comment: On a side note, you should be using the list invocation of system() so you don't have to worry about quoting and shell injection: "system('convert', $jpg, $png);".

Comment: Fat commas make everything better: 'system( convert => ($jpg, $png));'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cribbed from the [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/dist/IPC-Run) manpage:

```
use IPC::Run qw{run timeout};
my ($in, $out, $err);

run [convert => ($jpg, $png)], \$in, \$out, \$err, timeout( 10 ) or die "$err (error $?)"
```

You could also use [PerlMagick](http://search.cpan.org/dist/PerlMagick) like this:

```
use Image::Magick;

my $p = new Image::Magick;
$p->Read($jpg);
$p->Write($png);
```

Comment: The `--quiet` should just be another entry in the array you pass to run: `run ['convert', '--quiet', $jpg, $png],` etc.  *(This is why fat commas are bad; they can confuse people into thinking there's magic syntax at work.)*

Comment: I assumed a certain level of Perl knowledge, given that this isn't just written using a shell script.  Anyway, you can do this *run [convert => -quiet => ($jpg, $png)], \$in, \$out, \$err, timeout( 10 ) or die "$err (error $?)"*  as you can see, the parameter is -quiet not --quiet

Comment: Or for Porculus: *run ['convert', '-quiet', $jpg, $png], \$in, \$out, \$err, timeout( 10 ) or die "$err (error $?)"*, as you can see the fat comma (*=>*) works like a regular comma except it causes its left operand to be interpreted as a string (as long as its a 'word', no whitespace, or sigils, see perlop for more details) which aids in comprehending the relationship between parameters in calls like system: i.e. better *system( cmd => ('param1', 'param2') );* than *system('cmd', 'param1', 'param2');*

Answer (score 0):

For best results see:
[How-can-I-capture-STDERR-from-an-external-command?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-can-I-capture-STDERR-from-an-external-command?)

Also read the previous one:

> Why can't I get the output of a
>   command with system()?

Comment: Your URL needed the '?': http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-can-I-capture-STDERR-from-an-external-command%3f

Answer (score 0):

As noted by MkV, IPC::Run is the best solution. Use that if possible.

If you are in a broken environment that does not allow you to install CPAN modules, a grotty workaround is to do a pipe hack with shell redirection:

```
open my $fh, '-|', "convert \Q$jpg\E \Q$png\E 2>&1"
    or die "Can't launch 'convert'";
```

...and then read and parse `$fh` as appropriate. The `\Q`...`\E` escapes the filenames, and is necessary to avoid problems with filenames that contain spaces or other shell metacharacters. You should also use them with `system()` to avoid the same problems.